# Css theme not effective on jquery changes

Tags: jquery, css, themes

I have come across a very weird issue using the css theme with jquery.

I have applied a custom css theme on a web page and the page looks great. Now i have performed a few operations using the jquery. Like on clicking a checkbox the other checkboxes gets checked and a few gets disabled.

Strangely the page still looked the same. that is the checkboxes which are checked/disabled still have the same images that were there before the jquery operation.

My colleagues tell me i have to apply css class after every jquery operation. Like for every check/uncheck of checkboxes

Is it suppose to be that way or am i doing something wrong?? I was under the impression that once the theme is installed the css will be consistent.

Any suggestions ...

Thanks..

Edit :

The code is extensive but I am attaching the uniform-default.css file and the js file used for applying. Let me know if you need any more code.

```
/* Global Declaration */
div.selector, 
div.selector span, 
div.checker span,
div.radio span, 
div.uploader, 
div.uploader span.action,
div.button,
div.button span {
  background-image: url(../resources/images/sprite.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

}

.selector, 
.radio, 
.checker, 
.uploader,
.button, 
.selector *, 
.radio *, 
.checker *, 
.uploader *,
.button *{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* INPUT & TEXTAREA */

input.text,
input.email, 
input.password,
textarea.uniform {
  padding: 2px;
  background:#fff url('../resources/images/bg-input-focus.png') repeat-x 0px 0px;
  background:#fff url('../resources/images/bg-input.png') repeat-x 0px 0px;
  border:1px solid #b7b7b7;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: 0;
}

input.text:focus,
input.email:focus,
input.password:focus,
textarea.uniform:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-color: #ababab;
  background:#fff url('../resources/images/bg-input-focus.png') repeat-x 0px 0px;
}
input.text[disabled], input.password[disabled], textarea.uniform[disabled], select[disabled]{color: #999; border:1px solid #dfdfdf;padding: 2px; background-color:#f3f3f3;}
/* SPRITES */

/* Select */

div.selector {
  background-position: -485px -130px;
  line-height: 26px;
  height: 26px;
}

div.selector span {
  background-position: right 0px;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
}

div.selector select {
  /* change these to adjust positioning of select element */
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;

}

div.selector:active, 
div.selector.active {
  background-position: -485px -156px;
}

div.selector:active span, 
div.selector.active span {
  background-position: right -26px;
}

div.selector.focus, div.selector.hover, div.selector:hover {
  background-position: -485px -182px;
}

div.selector.focus span, div.selector.hover span, div.selector:hover span {
  background-position: right -52px;
}

div.selector.focus:active,
div.selector.focus.active,
div.selector:hover:active,
div.selector.active:hover {
  background-position: -485px -208px;
}

div.selector.focus:active span,
div.selector:hover:active span,
div.selector.active:hover span,
div.selector.focus.active span {
  background-position: right -78px;
}

div.selector.disabled {
  background-position: -485px -234px;
}

div.selector.disabled span {
  background-position: right -104px;
}

/* Checkbox */

div.checker {
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
}

div.checker input {
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
}

div.checker span {
  background-position: 0px -260px;
  height: 19px;
  width: 19px;
}

div.checker:active span, 
div.checker.active span {
  background-position: -19px -260px;
}

div.checker.focus span,
div.checker:hover span {
  background-position: -38px -260px;
}

div.checker.focus:active span,
div.checker:active:hover span,
div.checker.active:hover span,
div.checker.focus.active span {
  background-position: -57px -260px;
}

div.checker span.checked {
  background-position: -76px -260px;
}

div.checker:active span.checked, 
div.checker.active span.checked {
  background-position: -95px -260px;
}

div.checker.focus span.checked,
div.checker:hover span.checked {
  background-position: -114px -260px;
}

div.checker.focus:active span.checked,
div.checker:hover:active span.checked,
div.checker.active:hover span.checked,
div.checker.active.focus span.checked {
  background-position: -133px -260px;
}

div.checker.disabled span,
div.checker.disabled:active span,
div.checker.disabled.active span {
  background-position: -152px -260px;
}

div.checker.disabled span.checked,
div.checker.disabled:active span.checked,
div.checker.disabled.active span.checked {
  background-position: -171px -260px;
}

/* Radio */

div.radio {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

div.radio input {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

div.radio span {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-position: 0px -279px;
}

div.radio:active span, 
div.radio.active span {
  background-position: -18px -279px;
}

div.radio.focus span, 
div.radio:hover span {
  background-position: -36px -279px;
}

div.radio.focus:active span,
div.radio:active:hover span,
div.radio.active:hover span,
div.radio.active.focus span {
  background-position: -54px -279px;
}

div.radio span.checked {
  background-position: -72px -279px;
}

div.radio:active span.checked,
div.radio.active span.checked {
  background-position: -90px -279px;
}

div.radio.focus span.checked, div.radio:hover span.checked {
  background-position: -108px -279px;
}

div.radio.focus:active span.checked, 
div.radio:hover:active span.checked,
div.radio.focus.active span.checked,
div.radio.active:hover span.checked {
  background-position: -126px -279px;
}

div.radio.disabled span,
div.radio.disabled:active span,
div.radio.disabled.active span {
  background-position: -144px -279px;
}

div.radio.disabled span.checked,
div.radio.disabled:active span.checked,
div.radio.disabled.active span.checked {
  background-position: -162px -279px;
}

/* Uploader */

div.uploader {
  background-position: 0px -297px;
  height: 28px;
}

div.uploader span.action {
  background-position: right -409px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

div.uploader span.filename {
  height: 24px;
  /* change this line to adjust positioning of filename area */
  margin: 2px 0px 2px 2px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

div.uploader.focus,
div.uploader.hover,
div.uploader:hover {
  background-position: 0px -353px;
}

div.uploader.focus span.action,
div.uploader.hover span.action,
div.uploader:hover span.action {
  background-position: right -437px;
}

div.uploader.active span.action,
div.uploader:active span.action {
  background-position: right -465px;
}

div.uploader.focus.active span.action,
div.uploader:focus.active span.action,
div.uploader.focus:active span.action,
div.uploader:focus:active span.action {
  background-position: right -493px;
}

div.uploader.disabled {
  background-position: 0px -325px;
}

div.uploader.disabled span.action {
  background-position: right -381px;
}

div.button {
  background-position: 0px -523px;
}

div.button span {
  background-position: right -643px;
}

div.button.focus,
div.button:focus,
div.button:hover,
div.button.hover {
  background-position: 0px -553px;
}

div.button.focus span,
div.button:focus span,
div.button:hover span,
div.button.hover span {
  background-position: right -673px; 
}

div.button.active,
div.button:active {
  background-position: 0px -583px;
}

div.button.active span,
div.button:active span {
  background-position: right -703px;
  color: #555;
}

div.button.disabled,
div.button:disabled {
  background-position: 0px -613px;
}

div.button.disabled span,
div.button:disabled span {
  background-position: right -733px;
  color: #bbb;
  cursor: default;
}

/* PRESENTATION */

/* Button */

div.button {
  height: 30px;
}


 ........... some more content here ......

div.selector span {
  padding: 0px 25px 0px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.selector span {
  color: #666;
 /* width: 158px;*/
 text-align:left;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

div.selector.disabled span {
  color: #bbb;
}

/* Checker */
div.checker {
 /* margin-right: 5px;*/
}

/* Radio */
div.radio {
  margin-right: 3px;
}

/* Uploader */
div.uploader {
  width: 190px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.uploader span.action {
  width: 85px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: #fff 0px 1px 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.uploader span.filename {
  color: #777;
  width: 82px;
  border-right: solid 1px #bbb;
  font-size: 11px;
}

div.uploader input {
  width: 190px;
}

div.uploader.disabled span.action {
  color: #aaa;
}

div.uploader.disabled span.filename {
  border-color: #ddd;
  color: #aaa;
}
/*

CORE FUNCTIONALITY 

Not advised to edit stuff below this line
-----------------------------------------------------
*/

.selector, 
.checker, 
.button, 
.radio, 
.uploader {
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}

.selector select:focus, .radio input:focus, .checker input:focus, .uploader input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

/* Button */

div.button a,
div.button button,
div.button input {
  position: absolute;
}

div.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

div.button span {
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Select */

div.selector {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.selector span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.selector select {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity:0);
  height: 25px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

/* Checker */

div.checker {
  position: relative;
}

div.checker span {
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

div.checker input {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity:0);
  display: inline-block;
  background: none;
}

    /* Radio */

div.radio {
  position: relative;
}

div.radio span {
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

div.radio input {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity:0);
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background: none;
}

/* Uploader */

div.uploader {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: default;
}

div.uploader span.action {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 2px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.uploader span.filename {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: default;
}

div.uploader input {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity:0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  float: right;
  height: 25px;
  border: none;
  cursor: default;    
    }
```

**and the js for it is attchaed below**

```
(function($) {
  $.uniform = {
    options: {
      selectClass:   'selector',
      radioClass: 'radio',
      checkboxClass: 'checker',
      fileClass: 'uploader',
      filenameClass: 'filename',
      fileBtnClass: 'action',
      fileDefaultText: 'No file selected',
      fileBtnText: 'Browse',
      checkedClass: 'checked',
      focusClass: 'focus',
      disabledClass: 'disabled',
     // buttonClass: 'button',
      activeClass: 'active',
      hoverClass: 'hover',
      useID: true,
      idPrefix: 'uniform',
      resetSelector: false,
      autoHide: true
    },
    elements: []
  };

  if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7){
    $.support.selectOpacity = false;
  }else{
    $.support.selectOpacity = true;
  }

  $.fn.uniform = function(options) {

    options = $.extend($.uniform.options, options);

    var el = this;
    //code for specifying a reset button
    if(options.resetSelector != false){
      $(options.resetSelector).mouseup(function(){
        function resetThis(){
          $.uniform.update(el);
        }
        setTimeout(resetThis, 10);
      });
    }

    function doInput(elem){
      $el = $(elem);
      $el.addClass($el.attr("type"));
      storeElement(elem);
    }

    function doTextarea(elem){
      $(elem).addClass("uniform");
      storeElement(elem);
    }

     function doSelect(elem){
      var $el = $(elem);

      var divTag = $('<div />'),
          spanTag = $('<span />');

      if(!$el.css("display") == "none" && options.autoHide){
        divTag.hide();
      }

      divTag.addClass(options.selectClass);

      if(options.useID && elem.attr("id") != ""){
        divTag.attr("id", options.idPrefix+"-"+elem.attr("id"));
      }

      var selected = elem.find(":selected:first");
      if(selected.length == 0){
        selected = elem.find("option:first");
      }
      spanTag.html(selected.html());

      elem.css('opacity', 0);
      elem.wrap(divTag);
      elem.before(spanTag);

      //redefine variables
      divTag = elem.parent("div");
      spanTag = elem.siblings("span");

      elem.bind({
        "change.uniform": function() {
          spanTag.text(elem.find(":selected").html());
          divTag.removeClass(options.activeClass);
        },
        "focus.uniform": function() {
          divTag.addClass(options.focusClass);
        },
        "blur.uniform": function() {
          divTag.removeClass(options.focusClass);
          divTag.removeClass(options.activeClass);
        },
        "mousedown.uniform touchbegin.uniform": function() {
          divTag.addClass(options.activeClass);
        },
        "mouseup.uniform touchend.uniform": function() {
          divTag.removeClass(options.activeClass);
        },
        "click.uniform touchend.uniform": function(){
          divTag.removeClass(options.activeClass);
        },
        "mouseenter.uniform": function() {
          divTag.addClass(options.hoverClass);
        },
        "mouseleave.uniform": function() {
          divTag.removeClass(options.hoverClass);
          divTag.removeClass(options.activeClass);
        },
        "keyup.uniform": function(){
          spanTag.text(elem.find(":selected").html());
        }
      });

      //handle disabled state
      if($(elem).attr("disabled")){
        //box is checked by default, check our box
        divTag.addClass(options.disabledClass);
      }
      $.uniform.noSelect(spanTag);

      storeElement(elem);

    }

    function doCheckbox(elem){
      var $el = $(elem);

      var divTag = $('<div />'),
          spanTag = $('<span />');

      if(!$el.css("display") == "none" && options.autoHide){
        divTag.hide();
      }

      divTag.addClass(options.checkboxClass);

      //assign the id of the element
      if(options.useID && elem.attr("id") != ""){
        divTag.attr("id", options.idPrefix+"-"+elem.attr("id"));
      }

      //wrap with the proper elements
      $(elem).wrap(divTag);
      $(elem).wrap(spanTag);

      //redefine variables
      spanTag = elem.parent();
      divTag = spanTag.parent();

      //hide normal input and add focus classes
      $(elem)
      .css("opacity", 0)
      .bind({
        "focus.uniform": function(){
          divTag.addClass(options.focusClass);
        },
        "blur.uniform": function(){
          divTag.removeClass(options.focusClass);
        },
        "click.uniform touchend.uniform": function(){
          if(!$(elem).attr("checked")){
            //box was just unchecked, uncheck span
            spanTag.removeClass(options.checkedClass);
          }else{
            //box was just checked, check span.
            spanTag.addClass(options.checkedClass);
          }
        },
        "mousedown.uniform touchbegin.uniform": function() {
          divTag.addClass(options.activeClass);
        },
        "mouseup.uniform touchend.uniform": function() {
          divTag.removeClass(options.activeClass);
        },
        "mouseenter.uniform": function() {
          divTag.addClass(options.hoverClass);
        },
        "mouseleave.uniform": function() {
          divTag.removeClass(options.hoverClass);
          divTag.removeClass(options.activeClass);
        }
      });

      //handle defaults
      if($(elem).attr("checked")){
        //box is checked by default, check our box
        spanTag.addClass(options.checkedClass);
      }

      //handle disabled state
      if($(elem).attr("disabled")){
        //box is checked by default, check our box
        divTag.addClass(options.disabledClass);
      }

      storeElement(elem);
    }

    function doRadio(elem){
      var $el = $(elem);

      var divTag = $('<div />'),
          spanTag = $('<span />');

      if(!$el.css("display") == "none" && options.autoHide){
        divTag.hide();
      }

      divTag.addClass(options.radioClass);

      if(options.useID && elem.attr("id") != ""){
        divTag.attr("id", options.idPrefix+"-"+elem.attr("id"));
      }

      //wrap with the proper elements
      $(elem).wrap(divTag);
      $(elem).wrap(spanTag);

      //redefine variables
      spanTag = elem.parent();
      divTag = spanTag.parent();

      //hide normal input and add focus classes
      $(elem)
      .css("opacity", 0)
      .bind({
        "focus.uniform": function(){
          divTag.addClass(options.focusClass);
        },
        "blur.uniform": function(){
          divTag.removeClass(options.focusClass);
        },
        "click.uniform touchend.uniform": function(){
          if(!$(elem).attr("checked")){
            //box was just unchecked, uncheck span
            spanTag.removeClass(options.checkedClass);
          }else{
            //box was just checked, check span
            var classes = options.radioClass.split(" ")[0];
            $("." + classes + " span." + options.checkedClass + ":has([name='" + $(elem).attr('name') + "'])").removeClass(options.checkedClass);
            spanTag.addClass(options.checkedClass);
          }
        },
        "mousedown.uniform touchend.uniform": function() {
          if(!$(elem).is(":disabled")){
            divTag.addClass(options.activeClass);
          }
        },
        "mouseup.uniform touchbegin.uniform": function() {
          divTag.removeClass(options.activeClass);
        },
        "mouseenter.uniform touchend.uniform": function() {
          divTag.addClass(options.hoverClass);
        },
        "mouseleave.uniform": function() {
          divTag.removeClass(options.hoverClass);
          divTag.removeClass(options.activeClass);
        }
      });

      //handle defaults
      if($(elem).attr("checked")){
        //box is checked by default, check span
        spanTag.addClass(options.checkedClass);
      }
      //handle disabled state
      if($(elem).attr("disabled")){
        //box is checked by default, check our box
        divTag.addClass(options.disabledClass);
      }

      storeElement(elem);

    }

    function doFile(elem){
      //sanitize input
      var $el = $(elem);

      var divTag = $('<div />'),
          filenameTag = $('<span>'+options.fileDefaultText+'</span>'),
          btnTag = $('<span>'+options.fileBtnText+'</span>');

      if(!$el.css("display") == "none" && options.autoHide){
        divTag.hide();
      }

      divTag.addClass(options.fileClass);
      filenameTag.addClass(options.filenameClass);
      btnTag.addClass(options.fileBtnClass);

      if(options.useID && $el.attr("id") != ""){
        divTag.attr("id", options.idPrefix+"-"+$el.attr("id"));
      }

      //wrap with the proper elements
      $el.wrap(divTag);
      $el.after(btnTag);
      $el.after(filenameTag);

      //redefine variables
      divTag = $el.closest("div");
      filenameTag = $el.siblings("."+options.filenameClass);
      btnTag = $el.siblings("."+options.fileBtnClass);

      //set the size
      if(!$el.attr("size")){
        var divWidth = divTag.width();
        //$el.css("width", divWidth);
        $el.attr("size", divWidth/10);
      }

      //actions
      var setFilename = function()
      {
        var filename = $el.val();
        if (filename === '')
        {
          filename = options.fileDefaultText;
        }
        else
        {
          filename = filename.split(/[\/\\]+/);
          filename = filename[(filename.length-1)];
        }
        filenameTag.text(filename);
      };

      // Account for input saved across refreshes
      setFilename();

      $el
      .css("opacity", 0)
      .bind({
        "focus.uniform": function(){
          divTag.addClass(options.focusClass);
        },
        "blur.uniform": function(){
          divTag.removeClass(options.focusClass);
        },
        "mousedown.uniform": function() {
          if(!$(elem).is(":disabled")){
            divTag.addClass(options.activeClass);
          }
        },
        "mouseup.uniform": function() {
          divTag.removeClass(options.activeClass);
        },
        "mouseenter.uniform": function() {
          divTag.addClass(options.hoverClass);
        },
        "mouseleave.uniform": function() {
          divTag.removeClass(options.hoverClass);
          divTag.removeClass(options.activeClass);
        }
      });

      // IE7 doesn't fire onChange until blur or second fire.
      if ($.browser.msie){
        // IE considers browser chrome blocking I/O, so it
        // suspends tiemouts until after the file has been selected.
        $el.bind('click.uniform.ie7', function() {
          setTimeout(setFilename, 0);
        });
      }else{
        // All other browsers behave properly
        $el.bind('change.uniform', setFilename);
      }

      //handle defaults
      if($el.attr("disabled")){
        //box is checked by default, check our box
        divTag.addClass(options.disabledClass);
      }

      $.uniform.noSelect(filenameTag);
      $.uniform.noSelect(btnTag);

      storeElement(elem);

    }

    $.uniform.restore = function(elem){
      if(elem == undefined){
        elem = $($.uniform.elements);
      }

      $(elem).each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checkbox")){
          //unwrap from span and div
          $(this).unwrap().unwrap();
        }else if($(this).is("select")){
          //remove sibling span
          $(this).siblings("span").remove();
          //unwrap parent div
          $(this).unwrap();
        }else if($(this).is(":radio")){
          //unwrap from span and div
          $(this).unwrap().unwrap();
        }else if($(this).is(":file")){
          //remove sibling spans
          $(this).siblings("span").remove();
          //unwrap parent div
          $(this).unwrap();
        }else if($(this).is("button, :submit, :reset, a, input[type='button']")){
          //unwrap from span and div
          $(this).unwrap().unwrap();
        }

        //unbind events
        $(this).unbind(".uniform");

        //reset inline style
        $(this).css("opacity", "1");

        //remove item from list of uniformed elements
        var index = $.inArray($(elem), $.uniform.elements);
        $.uniform.elements.splice(index, 1);
      });
    };

    function storeElement(elem){
      //store this element in our global array
      elem = $(elem).get();
      if(elem.length > 1){
        $.each(elem, function(i, val){
          $.uniform.elements.push(val);
        });
      }else{
        $.uniform.elements.push(elem);
      }
    }

    //noSelect v1.0
    $.uniform.noSelect = function(elem) {
      function f() {
       return false;
      };
      $(elem).each(function() {
       this.onselectstart = this.ondragstart = f; // Webkit & IE
       $(this)
        .mousedown(f) // Webkit & Opera
        .css({ MozUserSelect: 'none' }); // Firefox
      });
     };

    $.uniform.update = function(elem){
      if(elem == undefined){
        elem = $($.uniform.elements);
      }
      //sanitize input
      elem = $(elem);

      elem.each(function(){
        //do to each item in the selector
        //function to reset all classes
        var $e = $(this);

        if($e.is("select")){
          //element is a select
          var spanTag = $e.siblings("span");
          var divTag = $e.parent("div");

          divTag.removeClass(options.hoverClass+" "+options.focusClass+" "+options.activeClass);

          //reset current selected text
          spanTag.html($e.find(":selected").html());

          if($e.is(":disabled")){
            divTag.addClass(options.disabledClass);
          }else{
            divTag.removeClass(options.disabledClass);
          }

        }else if($e.is(":checkbox")){
          //element is a checkbox
          var spanTag
```

Comment: No you don't have to apply css after every operation. Sharing some of your code will help. Are proper css classes getting added after your operation?

Comment: I have added the .css and the .js file . There are other files too. But i think these two are the main. Please let me know if u need more code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that CSS is loaded before the JS ?

```
<head>
  <!-- import css -->
  <!-- import jquery -->
</head>
<body>
<!--
Your awesome page
-->
...
...
<!-- JS affecting the DOM should be called after all the elements gets rendered -->
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes i tried it ... its doesnt solve the issue ... :(